# Encode String to Unicode

Tags: ios, unicode, swift2

I want to encode `String` from `UITextField` to Unicode in order to transform emojis from :

```
Hello
```

To Unicode :

```
Hello \\uD83D\\uDE00
```

I found how to decode with this func :

```
static func decodeUnicode(input: String) -> String? {
    let ns = NSString(string: input)
    let data:NSData = ns.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    return NSString(data:data,encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding) as? String
}
```

But not how to encode.

Comment: Did you try? `let data:NSData = ns.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!`

Comment: Perfect, I had just to switch NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding and NSUTF8StringEncoding !

Answer (score 0):

This Java method worked for me:

```
    public String convertToUnicode(String inputString) {
        int c = 0;
        String outputString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        {
            c = inputString.charAt(i);
            outputString = outputString + "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(c | 0x10000).substring(1);
        }
        return outputString;
    }
```